# Asfactory implementation in ninject in contrast to Castle

Tags: ninject

I am pretty new to castle and Ninject . how ever i have a statement where an Interface is initialised as factory method as like this

```
public class LazySessionContext
{
    private readonly ISessionFactoryImplementor factory;
    private const string CurrentSessionContextKey = "NHibernateCurrentSession";

    public LazySessionContext(ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
    }
}
```

Now when injecting ISessionFactoryImplementor  as factory method we have done like this

```
public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {


        container.Register(Component.For<ISessionFactoryProvider>().AsFactory());

        container.Register(Component.For<IEnumerable<ISessionFactory>>()
                                    .UsingFactoryMethod(k => k.ResolveAll<ISessionFactory>()));

    }
```

can someone please mention how to achieve the same in ninject ? so as the ISessionFactoryProvider is provided and initialised as a factory method in ninject ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
kernel.Bind<ISessionFactoryProvider>().ToFactory();
```

is the equivalent. to this configuration. You have to use Ninject.Extensions.Factory. The IEnumerable configuration exists by default.

Comment: Thanks for telling about the extension didnt knew about extensions for ninject :)